# need oracle sql to print only year month day and hour

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i just print the date in this format?'YYYY MM DD HH24'
the data printed is not in the format that is put in the query.

The source data is in UTC. i can successfully convert it to EST but cannot limit it to just date and hour.

```
    select  NEW_TIME(request_Date_time, 'GMT', 'EST') request_date_time_EST , TO_DATE (NEW_TIME(request_Date_time, 'GMT', 'EST'), 'YYYY MM DD HH24') 
  
from  report
where rownum<10
```

this is what i get
[image: results]

Comment: What is NEW_TIME? Concretely, what data type is request_date_time, and what data type does NEW_TIME return? Note that you are calling TO_DATE on whatever the function returns; that is not how you format a date as string, in a desired format. That should be TO_CHAR. But for more help, you must answer my questions first.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions092.htm
NEW_TIME converts from 1 timezone info to anothertimezone. i have the request_Date_time in GMT. I need to convert it to EST.

Comment: i got the clue and fixed the query.
select  NEW_TIME(request_Date_time, 'GMT', 'EST') request_date_time_EST ,  to_char( (NEW_TIME(request_Date_time, 'GMT', 'EST')), 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
  
from report
where rownum<10